# Button html tag not working

Tags: html

I have a simple form that searches in a database  as following:

```
<form action="search.html" method="get" name="search" class="field">
<input type="text" id="q" name="q" placeholder="what are you searching for?" />
<button type="button" id="search" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="Submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

When I click on submit button, it doesn't do anything, why could be that ?

Thanks

Comment: change button type to submit <button type="submit" id="search" name="Submit" value="Submit" >Search</button>

Comment: What do you want to do with this form ? action ="search.html" ?? where is your code when you submit form ?

Comment: Using button type submit worked, thank you Rp9

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `type` attribute two times:

```
<button type="button" id="search" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="Submit">Search</button>
        ^ here                                                 ^ and here
```

Remove the first one since it is not allowed to have the same attribute multiple times.

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose
>   names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes